# 'Unexpected token import' while testing in create-react-app

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

when I run npm test in my project folder, I get an error message saying `unexpected token import`.
As I am using create-react-app, I assume I don't have to configure anything because everything is supposed to work out-of-the-box.

I dont understand if I am making a mistake somewhere or its a create-react-app issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this question from Google:

The error `unexpected token import` is often a sign that something is wrong with parsing your ES6 code, since `import` isn't a feature in earlier version. Often, browsers such as Chrome will run ES6, but you'll encounter the error when you go to run tests. Hence, running `yarn test` with `create-react-app` will expose this error.

The immediate solution, is to look at how babel is compiling your ES6 code. In the example above, `create-react-app` has come with webpack and babel included. However, they assume that your `node_modules` are already compiled, and this are skipped over in the compiling process. So, even though you have babel in your project, it's not compiling all your ES6 *for some reason*.

If you're using a different project that doesn't come with webpack/babel pre-setup, or wrote a custom setup for babel, that's where you should investigate first.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue with `create-react-app`.

I had my code in `src/node_modules` folder which was not being transformed by babel as it excludes the `node_modules`.

Comment: I had the same issue / solution. My ``node_modules`` was including a dependency that was written in ES6, but wasn't compiled. I had assumed by babel install would process it, but the ``create-react-app`` doesn't run babel/webpack on ``node_modules``.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because your babel is not configured correctly.

Comment: I don't have to configure babel. That's the whole point of using create-react-app.

Comment: what OS do you use?

Comment: linux debian. How is it relevant?

Comment: if it is linux-like OS, it should not be any problems theoretically.